# How to set set url parameter with special character in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want setting like this

```
localhost:3000/some-special-days-one--parameterThat
```

How Can I setting and getting in router like  this url and parameter in node js express framework?

Comment: You posted this exact same question just a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960579/how-to-set-set-url-parameter-with-special-character-in-node-js-express-framework

Comment: @ZoeCarver I have erased that question ? Sorry

Comment: Do not ask the same question over and over again! If your previous question got deleted, there is probably a reason.

Comment: What code have you tried and where did you get stuck?  A `-` is not a special character in URLs.  It's just a normal URL character.  The appropriate way to specify parameters at the end of a URI is as a query parameter `http://locahost/somePath?someParm=somevalue`.

Comment: @Zoecarver You right? Im sorry.

Comment: @jfiriend I dont want http://locahost/somePath?someParm=somevalue or query string I know that but I want making like this

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking, do you want to be able to send them to a url like this: `localhost:3000/some-id`?

Comment: Yes @ZoeCarver but with to parameters localhost:3000/firstParameter--someId.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks @ZoeCarver. How can I do ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you are trying to do:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.get('/firstParameter/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send('my id is: ' + req.params.id);//this is the id
}); 

app.listen(3000);
```

In this example, if the user went to the URL `localhost:3000/firstParameter/someId`, The page would show "my id is: someId".

Hope this helps!

PS

If you do not want to have the `/` you can simply do:

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
      var id = req.params.id;
      idArr = id.split("firstParameter--");
      id = idArr[1];

      res.send('my id is: ' + id); //this is the id
});
```

Then, like above, just go to `http://localhost:3000/firstParameter--hello`and it will print out "my id is: hello"

Comment: You are awesome :) Thank you :)

Comment: No problem! happy to help :)

Comment: So @ZoeCarver how can I do :id parameter without "/" charecters ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant hope this helps :|